# php: синглтон для работы с БД

Tags: php, база-данных, классы, запрос

написал вот такой код для работы с БД:

```
class CConnectionSingleton
{
    private static $_instance = null;

    private static $_db_address     = 'xxx';
    private static $_db_logon       = 'xxx';
    private static $_db_password    = 'xxx';
    private static $_db_goods_db    = 'xxx';

    private $_connection = null;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$_instance != null) {
            return self::$_instance;
        }

        return new self;
    }

    private function __construct () {

        $_connection = new mysqli($_db_address , $_db_logon, $_db_password, $_db_goods_db);

    }

    private function __clone () {}
    private function __wakeup () {}

    // закрыть соединение
    public function closeConnection()
    {
        $_connection->close();
    }

    // получить данные по запросу в БД
    public function sql2data($query)
    {
        // выполнить запрос в БД
        $result = $_connection->query($query);

        // сформировать результат
        $data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        // очистить память после выполнения sql запроса
        do{} while($_connection->more_results() && $_connection->next_result());

        // сформировать json строку по результату
        return $data;       
    }

    // перевести результат sql запроса в json
    public function sql2json($query)
    {
        // сформировать json строку по результату
        return json_encode($this->sql2data($query));       
    }

    // выполнить запрос в БД
    public function sql2simple($query)
    {
        // выполнить запрос в БД
        $result = $_connection->query($query);  
    }
}
```

Вызываю следующим образом:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

<?php

    include ('test.php');

    // установить соединение
    $connection = CConnectionSingleton::getInstance();

    $queryData = $connection->sql2json("SELECT * FROM table;");

?>

<script>

    var data = <?php echo json_encode($queryData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>;

    console.log(JSON.parse(data));

</script>   

    </body>
</html>
```

PHP ругается на

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   test.php on line 42

line 42 - это

> $result = $_connection->query($query);

В чем может быть проблема?

Что-то туплю, ошибка то элементарная

**P.S.**

Ещё не понятно, если меняю

```
return json_encode($this->sql2data($query));
```

на

```
return json_encode(sql2data($query));
```

ловлю на этой строчке ошибку

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sql2data() in test.php on line
>   58

Вроде же из метода класса обратился к тому же методу, зачем явно указывать это

Comment: Ваш синглтон таковым не является - вы забыли присвоить новый инстанс в статическое поле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл одну ошибку - соединение не устанавливалось,
Исправил код:

```
$_connection = new mysqli(self::$_db_address, self::$_db_logon, self::$_db_password, self::$_db_goods_db);
```

основную ошибку это не исправило, но теперь устанавливается соединение

проверил внутри функции `sql2data` - там переменная _connection уже не определена :(

**P.S.**

**ВСЁ, НАШЕЛ И ИСПРАВИЛ ОШИБКУ**

Надо было обращаться к `$_connection` через `$this`

например,

```
$this->_connection = new mysqli(self::$_db_address, self::$_db_logon, self::$_db_password, self::$_db_goods_db);
```

или

```
$result = $this->_connection->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в php нет сокращенного синтаксиса обращения к полям объекта/класса.
Т.е. `$this->`/`self::` нельзя опустить, они обязательны.

В случае их отсутствия, всегда подразумевается обычная локальная переменная.

---

Итак, `$this->_connection = new mysqli...`, `$this->_connection->close()` и т.д.

Comment: ага, сейчас методом проб и ошибок нашел это решение, странно что php поставил такие жесткие ограничения